# Use same controller with associations in top-level and nested paths in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, controller

I would like my REST API to have several routes, such as:

```
GET /posts/
GET /posts/1
POST /posts

GET /users/
GET /users/1
GET /users/1/posts
POST /users/1/posts
```

Is it possible to reuse the same controller for those nested routes under the users collection?

Comment: It is, but it is highly version dependent. Perhaps edit your question to specify a rails version.

Comment: I'm on Rails 6.0.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want nested routes. Try this is your config/routes.rb

```
resources :posts
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

This has more info. You could also use `match` or `post` and `get` verb methods individually. There are also many options for nested routes.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

ALTERNATIVELY

in config/routes.rb:

```
get 'users/:id/posts', to: 'users#posts'
```

and in controllers/users_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:users_posts, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...
def posts
  @posts = @user.posts
end
```

With the second option you can KISS by keeping POST/PATCH/UPDATE/DESTROY at their native home like /posts and /posts/42. Just treat :user_id as a form variable in that case, with whatever extra validation you might need, perhaps referencing a session var.

LASTLY

You can actually put this in your config/routes.rb. But now you're probably writing new forms because :user_id is a route parameter. I'd file that under extra complexity. Maybe it fits your situation though.

```
post 'users/:id/posts', to: 'users#posts_create'
```

Comment: This is correct, but I want to figure out the best way to keep controllers slim while also handling associations. For example, in this case, I could have an `index` route to retrieve all Posts or an `index` route to retrieve all Posts of a particular user. Is there a good way to keep the code for that slim and maybe use the same function for both?

Comment: Yes, the option I presented needs some extra work in the controllers. It wont work out of the box like you'd expect with scaffolds. You might try the http verbs or even the #match method in your routes. Depends on your situation. I added those options to the answer.

Comment: I guess I will settle for you alternative option, maybe there isn't anything better, haha.